# Decrease cursor size on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, cursor, resize

So, there's a setting to "*Decrease text size*" on ubuntu, and it makes everything smaller. That's good for low quality screens. But after doing that, cursor is bigger than everything on screen. So how can I decrease cursor size than the smallest cursor size that's on settings?